# Getting USB data for OS X /dev/tty.* entry

Tags: macos, usb, tty

I am trying to (programatically in Java, though running external scripts is a possibility) get the USB idProduct, idVendor and ideally the string descriptors for the manufacturer and product for a USB device.

The device has (and it is all I am provided with in the beginning) a /dev/tty.usbmodem entry, and I need some way to reliably map that back to the USB information, but I can't find anything that relates one to the other (or rather I don't know where to look).

The device in question has the /dev entry of:

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   10,   2 18 Jul 15:08 /dev/tty.usbmodem9f31
```

`system_profiler` gives me the following USB information for the device:

```
<dict>
    <key>_name</key>
    <string>Stk500v2</string>
    <key>a_product_id</key>
    <string>0xa662</string>
    <key>b_vendor_id</key>
    <string>0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)</string>
    <key>c_bcd_device</key>
    <string> 1.80</string>
    <key>e_device_speed</key>
    <string>full_speed</string>
    <key>f_manufacturer</key>
    <string>www.cpustick.com</string>
    <key>g_location_id</key>
    <string>0x9f300000</string>
    <key>h_bus_power</key>
    <string>500</string>
    <key>j_bus_power_used</key>
    <string>500</string>
</dict>
```

I can see the prefix of 0x9f3 for the g_location_id matching the start of the dev entry's suffix of 9f31, but I don't know a) how reliable that would be, and b) what the "1" would represent at the end, and how that would be affected by having multiple of the same device on the same bus, and how you would differentiate between them.

I have other devices I need to do this with as well, and they don't all follow the same naming rules.  One of them uses the USB serial number field for the suffix. Other potential ones (that I don't have control over at all) could do it differently again I guess.

So basically I need some way of mapping the textual device name /dev/tty.whatever to a physical USB device entry that I can then pull the data I need from.  On Linux I do it by traversing the /sys tree from /sys/class/tty through to /sys/devices/pci...blahblah/usb[x]/wherever but I can find no similar facility on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get the USB vendor ID and product ID of a serial port on Mac OS X.

Also, there is a library called libserialport that you could use:

http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport

Comment: IOKit looks the way forward - it was the missing link in my chain.  Libserialport would mean me writing an external helper program which I'd rather avoid - I'd prefer to use system installed binaries if at all possible.  Parsing `ioreg` may be the way to do it.  Are you aware of a Java wrapper to it at all? I had a google, but IOKit seems to be a bit ambiguous...